# How to make netcdf time format as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS from YYYY-MM-DD HH?

Tags: netcdf

My `netcdf4` file has the following header for the time variable

```
    float time(time) ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:long_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0" ;
        time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
```

With the following command

```
ncdump -tv time infile.nc
```

time format looks like

```
"2009-12-31 22"
```

I want to make it so that it is like

```
"2020-12-31 22:00"
```

How do I achieve this with either `nco` or `cdo`??

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not huge you could try

```
cdo -outputtab,date,time infile.nc | sort | uniq
```

I think it also assumes that time is the unlimited dimension, and may produce errors otherwise.